# Do I need OK TO BOARD to transit UAE?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, uae, ok-to-board

my traveller Indian Passport holder will fly from Delhi to Djibouti via Dubai on FlyDubai. Visa will be on arrival and have an invitation letter for tourist purpose. Do he requires OK TO BOARD message in his PNR as he is holding ECR (Emigration Check Required) passport. Please assist

Comment: @NRandhawa OK to Board is a special process required for Indian, Pakistani and some other nationalities passengers who are flying from India to UAE.

Comment: @Michael Hampton tnx, i had never heard that before.

Answer (score 1):

The [flydubai website FAQ](https://www.flydubai.com/en/contact/faq) states, in relevant part:

> **When do I need an OK to Board approval to fly with flydubai?**
>
> An OK to Board approval from flydubai is mandatory for India and Pakistan citizens travelling from the below cities:
>
> **Indian citizens:** flying from Kochi, Kozhikode, Delhi or Hyderabad. The approval is required only if you have a paper visa or an electronic visa with the below conditions:
>
> - **Tourist or Visit visa:** OK to Board required in case of ECR passports only.
> - **Employment visa:** OK to Board required irrespective of ECR or ECNR passports.
> - **Stamped visa:** OK to Board not required.
>
> **Approval for OK to Board**
>
> When you've paid for your booking, you can contact a local flydubai office or one of the [flydubai travel shops](https://www.flydubai.com/en/contact/travel-shops) in UAE, India or Pakistan (depending on where your visa is being processed) for the approval. Nominal charges will apply. Operating hours for flydubai local offices may vary.
>
> **Please note:** your departure and return flight must be booked with flydubai. Please make sure to submit your original visa, passport copy, and booking receipt. It is your responsibility to obtain the approval prior to your departure. If you arrive at the airport without an OK to Board approval, you will not be allowed to check in and board your flight. flydubai will not be responsible for any losses you may incur as a result, including providing any refund of any amounts paid.

Obviously this doesn't make anything more clear for your circumstance. I *suspect* that because you are only transiting UAE that you do not require OK to Board, but to avoid all doubt, you should contact your local flydubai office or travel shop regarding OK to Board.

Comment: I wonder what a "stamped visa" is. (And why they don't say anything about under which conditions the local offices will issue their approval ... do you just pay a fee? do they check something else? your credit report? do they flip a coin?)

Comment: @HenningMakholm I asked a [new](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/141726/47855) question about the criteria for getting an OK to Board.

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's a visa label applied directly to a passport page. This is commonly called "stamping" in India, though no actual stamp has been involved for many years. UAE also issues visas printed on separate sheets of paper as well as e-visas. The OK to Board scheme came about as a response to a high number of fake UAE paper visas. In this scheme, the airline verifies the visa before passenger check-in.